# Adding hover effects for submenu when hovering on menu

Tags: css, menu, hover

How can i add transitions/other hover effects when hovering on the menulink?

Code: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=show-hide-dropdown-on-mouse-hover

[Try to hover on the "Products submenu"]

Thx!

P.S.: I tried to add some css3 transitions but nothing happened..:/

Answer (score 0):

sub menu will fade in and out when hovering

```
   ul li ul{
      opacity:0;
      transition:opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   }

   ul li:hover ul{
      opacity:1;
   }
```

do not use display:none and block. use opacity instead.

Comment: I'd like to change the '.kenyer' div's transition and hover effects when hovering on 'Products' menu